# Is it possible to automatically print filename in a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, printing

I need to print the filename to my pdf (in the header or footer).

I'm using Adobe Reader, but i can also use Foxit pdf reader or anyother free pdf reader.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: if you're willing to use the command line and install `ghostscript` and `pdftk`, the related [Print PDF file with file path in footer](http://superuser.com/questions/171790/print-pdf-file-with-file-path-in-footer) has usable answers.

Answer (score 3):

To the late googlers, I made a program that will do this for free, sourcecode included:
[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HivH8cNQRDY)
[Site](http://www.saintjohnny.com/)
[Download link](http://www.saintjohnny.com/pdffilenamelabeler/files/pdffilenamelabeler.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Adobe Reader by writing a filename in notes:

1. Add a Sticky note
2. Write a filename
3. Go to Comments and then to the option icon
4. Go to Comments preferences
5. Mark "Print notes and pop-ups".

*I'm using portuguese written Adobe Reader, so it maybe not be exactly like an english one.*

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Foxit, however I can confirm this capability does not exist in Adobe Reader.

It is **very** simple in Adobe Acrobat, if you can access that software. Tools->Header and Footer->Add Header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to use a [commercial application](http://www.printandshare.info):

1. Go to the Get More Editor
2. Click "Insert text with parameters"
3. Add "Print job name"

[image]

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7prDkHA_AY&index=25&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a bit of a late response:

Irfanview https://www.irfanview.com/ is  a image editor and PDF viewer. I have been using it for various reasons for 15 years or more, most recently to convert PDF pages to JPG format.

In the Print dialog (when printing a PDF) you can add a header with $D for directory and $F for filename to print the directory and filename automatically. These options will apply to subsequent prints of new files until removed by the user.

Happy Printing!

Answer (score -1):

Using PDF Reader:

1. Click the [Sign] option (fountain pen)on the top toolbar.
2. Click in your document where you want to put the file name (you may have to click twice), and then type the text.  You can also make your text larger/smaller, expand it, insert a bullet, etc.
3. You can then select [Next] and save your document with the text added, or just print the file.

Comment: OP wanted to know how to AUTOMATICALLY add the file name.