How to get the (computer drive) file location to be printed (as header or footer) on my printed paper?
Here are the details of my problem. I am to print various papers with my home printer for personal research/projects/works.
After printing the paper, I often to go to the computer for that file, but this time I am to search for several minutes/folders for finding the file location in my drive. Would you please provide a way to get my file location printed along with the paper?
Say, my file location is as follows:
F:\2. We\Hasib\1-Printed pdfs\#My published papers\3-SE_34-3-w-pages-27-29

In above, 3-SE_34-3-w-pages-27-29 is the PDD file I want to be printed, and F:\2. We\Hasib\1-Printed pdfs\#My published papers is the location of that PDF that I want to be printed as header or footer in my print-out.

Hi Abdul. There is a duplicate question also on SuperUser with 3 answers and a lot of detail. https://superuser.com/questions/171790/print-pdf-file-with-file-path-in-footer
